# cq5 currentNode.identifier in clientlibs javascript

Tags: javascript, aem

I am able to get the value of '${currentNode.identifier}' in JSP javascript functions.

When I put the same js function and try to access the '${currentNode.identifier}' inside clientlibs javascript file , it simply outputting the string. not the actual identifier.

**

> How to access the current node identfier inside a client libe js file
>   or inside a  listener js function ?

**

I appreciate all the help.

Thanks,
Sri

Comment: It is not possible to access it directly in your JavaScript file. You need to output it somewhere in your HTML and then read it from the DOM in your JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As rakhi already mentioned in the comment: JavaScripts are delivered "as is" and are not executable servlets like JSPs. So there will be no replacement of scriptlets and ${} attributes. So the easiest way is to have a data attribute on a DIV or any other HTML element which is rendered by a JSP:

```
<div data-nodeid="${currentNode.identifier}"></div>
```

Then you could use a jQuery selector to get the value on load:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('div[data-nodeid]').each(function() {
        var nodeId = jQuery(this).data('nodeid');
        //do something with the id
    });
}
```